# Get table data behind button press with selenium in strange format

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to get table data from [this site.](https://www.countyhealthrankings.org/explore-health-rankings/county-health-rankings-model/health-outcomes/length-of-life/infant-mortality?year=2023&state=01&tab=1) I am having issues: the majority of the data is locked behind a button press, and once the button *is* pressed, the table data isn't within the html? I can see it from the web inspector, but this is confusing me. Here is my code so far:

```
def getData(state, year):
    url = f"https://www.countyhealthrankings.org/explore-health-rankings/county-health-rankings-model/health-outcomes/length-of-life/infant-mortality?year={year}&state={state}&tab=1"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda x: x.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
        button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(), "Show")]')
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
        table = driver.find_element('#state-snapshot-data-table')
        
    except Exception as e:
        return pd.DataFrame()
    finally:
        driver.quit()

    rows = table.find('tbody').find_all('tr')
    data = []
    for row in rows:
        cells = row.find_all('td')
        name = cells[0].text.strip()
        numerator = cells[1].text.strip()
        raw_value = cells[2].text.strip()
        ci_range = cells[3].text.strip()
        data.append([name, numerator, raw_value, ci_range])

    return pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name', 'numerator', 'raw_value', 'ci_range'])

print( getData('01', '2023') )
```

Any clarification or pointers on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a couple of issues with your function.

**First:** 
you are hiding any error related to table search.
[except Exception is a really bad practice](https://jerrynsh.com/stop-using-exceptions-like-this-in-python/)

**Second:**
You are quitting the driver in the 'finally' block. This means the driver won't be available at the moment when you will be looking for the rows.
The '**finally'** block gets executed **always**, no matter if there was an exception or not.

**Third:**
You are using selenium methods/locators incorrectly. E.g. using find_element w/o 'By', or using find/find_all methods which don't exist at all. Also, you are using /span tag instead of the /button. So your button cannot be clicked.

The following code works ok for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


def getData(state, year):
    url = f"https://www.countyhealthrankings.org/explore-health-rankings/county-health-rankings-model/health-outcomes/" \
          f"length-of-life/infant-mortality?year={year}&state={state}&tab=1"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda x: x.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')

        button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Show')]"))
        )
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', button)
        rows = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'state-snapshot-data-table') \
            .find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'tbody') \
            .find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')
        data = []
        for row in rows:
            cells = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')
            name = cells[0].text.strip()
            numerator = cells[1].text.strip()
            raw_value = cells[2].text.strip()
            ci_range = cells[3].text.strip()
            data.append([name, numerator, raw_value, ci_range])
        return pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name', 'numerator', 'raw_value', 'ci_range'])
    finally:
        driver.quit()

print(getData('01', '2023'))
```

In case of any issue - the function will fail - that's fine, you should check the stack trace and see what exactly went wrong.